# How to retrieve Auction-Time with Beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the timer on the next auction site to make a Sniper:

> http://www.vakantieveilingen.nl/veiling-van-de-dag.html

I need to get the auction time which i can find in:

```html
<div class="auction-time"> 
  <span class="h-init h-time-tick 
        ng-valid ng-binding ng-dirty" 
        ng-hide="popup.laughingSecondPrice > 0"
        ng-model="auction.time" ng-bind-html="auction.time.left|timeLeftFormatForBiedWidget"
        h-model-name="expires"><strong>03</strong><i>:</i><strong>31</strong>
  </span> 
  <span ng-show="popup.laughingSecondPrice > 0" class="ng-hide">Gesloten</span>
</div>
```

I can't find a right way to do it. Could anyone show me the way?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to grab the `span` element in the `div` element with the `auction-time` class:

```
auction_time_span = soup.select('.auction-time span.h-time-tick')[0]
print(auction_time_span.get_text())
```

The [`element.get_text()` function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) then returns the string value contained.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.vakantieveilingen.nl/veiling-van-de-dag.html')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
>>> soup.select('.auction-time span.h-time-tick')[0].get_text()
u'2015-02-02T22:32:00+01:00'
```

The time and date in the HTML served is converted to a relative time by Javascript code in the browser.

Comment: u'2015-02-02T22:32:00+01:00' is not the same as the Auction-END-time (?)  or am i wrong

Comment: @FrEaKi: That's what is contained in the HTML served to the browser. *Javascript code* may alter the display of this.

Comment: @FrEaKi: what value were you expecting instead?

Comment: I was expecting at every iteration (every 1 second): <strong>03</strong><i>:</i><strong>31</strong> and Then to strip this so i have 3.31

Comment: or at least miliseconds

Comment: @FrEaKi: your browser takes the ISO 8601 timestamp and turns that into a relative time. You can do the same in Python.